# How to assign values to a Map in java

Tags: java

I get requestParameters Map from my app and assigning it to a different `map` with some changed values. Basically output I get is

```
email=a@a.com
login
projectname=abc
```

I want to assign

```
email=a@a.com
request=login
projectname=abc
```

So i did this

```
    tempKey=new String[requestParameters.size()];
    tempValue=new String[requestParameters.size()];
    requestParams=new HashMap();

    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {

        Map.Entry me=(Map.Entry)iterator.next();
        String[] arr=(String[])me.getValue();

        if(me.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("login"))
        {
            tempKey[i]="request";
            tempValue[i]=me.getKey().toString();

        }
        else
        {
            tempValue[i]=arr[0];
            tempKey[i]=me.getKey().toString();
        }

        requestParams.put(tempKey[i], tempValue[i]);
        log.info(tempKey[i]+"="+tempValue[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

I try to print the values from `requestParams` like this, but i get nothing

```
iterator=requestParams.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {

        Map.Entry me=(Map.Entry)iterator.next();
        String[] arr=(String[])me.getValue();
        log.info(me.getKey().toString()+"="+arr[0]);
    }
```

It correctly prints the `log` using `tempKey[i]+"="+tempValue[i]` but it does not assign values to `requestParams` (modified map), What is wrong in the above code?

Comment: Why are you using these `tempValue` and `tempKey` arrays?

Comment: just ignore that, i was doing some other stuff with it, testing purpose

Comment: Rather than telling us to ignore things, why not fix the example? There's far too much that we're not seeing here - please change the question to show a short but *complete* example, saying what you're seeing and what you're expecting to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would copy the existing map and change the different values:

```
Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<String, String>(requestParameters);
newMap.put("request", "login");
newMap.remove("login");
```

Answer (score 0):

the request parameters map, normally is an unmodifiable map .. therefore any changes you make to the make will not be saved.  You need to create another map and put the all the entries in your map which you can change.